# Error handling in Makefile

Tags: lua, makefile

What is wrong with this Makefile?

I want to compile some lua files to check if there are any unexpected globals defined. I'm doing this by grepping the output of luac -l and then ignoring known globals.

So for a given lua file everything is OK if grep doesn't find anything, having ignored known lua globals.

As grep's return status code is 0 if it does find something and 1 if it doesn't I want to force an error if the status code from the grep is 0 and allow everything to continue if it isn't.

The Makefile is like this

```
IGNORE_GLOBALS = "dofile\|string\|tostring\|tonumber\|math\|io\|type\|os\|table\|pairs\|next\|require"

all: $(patsubst src/common/%.lua, %.lua, $(wildcard src/common/*.lua))

%.lua: 
    @echo check $@
    @luac -l src/common/$@  | grep '.ETGLOBAL' | grep -v $(IGNORE_GLOBALS) && $(error Unexpected globals in $@) || echo "No unexpected globals in $@"
```

But when I run it immediately quits on the first file, which happens to have no unexpected globals with

```
Makefile:10: *** Unexpected globals in chat-cmd.lua. Stop.
```

line 10 is surprisingly the line before, i.e.

```
@echo check $@
```

Interestingly if I replace $(error ...) with echo ..., as in

```
@luac -l src/common/$@  | grep '.ETGLOBAL' | grep -v $(IGNORE_GLOBALS) && echo "Unexpected globals in $@" || echo "No unexpected globals in $@"
```

it behaves as intended.

Comment: `error` is a builtin function (in GNU Make), so the `$(error ...)` is evaluated when the target `%.lua` is invoked, before the command line is passed to the shell.

Comment: @siffiejoe OK, so what should I be using instead of $(error ...) to force the Makefile to stop?

Comment: Try `... | grep -v $(IGNORE_GLOBALS) && echo "unexpected globals" && exit 1 || echo "no unexpected globals"`

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer `X && Y || Z` is not a ternary expression/statement in the shell. It will work in this case since only the pipeline can ever fail but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @siffiejoe says in the comment. `$(error)` is make function and is run when the recipe as a whole is being evaluated (you can think of it like hoisting if that helps).

So as soon as the recipe needs to be run (and the first line executed) the `$(error)` call is evaluated.

Note: In the shell `X && Y || Z` is *not* a ternary operation. `Z` will be run if `X` succeeds and `Y` fails as well as when `X` fails. This doesn't matter here as `echo` cannot really fail but in general is worth paying attention to.

You want to use something more like `@! lua ... | grep -v $(IGNORE_GLOBALS) || { echo 'Unexpected globals in $@'; exit 1; }` there. This doesn't spit out the "everything's ok" message but removes the `X && Y || Z` ternary issue.

If you wanted to keep that message the simplest thing to do would be to move to an actual `if` statement.

Comment: I appreciate you said 'like' `! grep ..`. If I use this as is I get `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "!" unexpected` even though ! is permitted in bash.

Comment: @MarkMelling Sorry, you can't negate part of a pipeline. You need to negate the entire pipeline. Try `@!lua ... | grep -v || { echo ...; }`.

Comment: Thanks, I think there needs to be a space in there i.e. `@! lua ...`

Comment: if you update your answer I can mark it as correct, or if you'd prefer I could do it (if that's the correct protocol!).